# hibernate - getCurrentSession - get is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm testing out hibernate 4.1.9 using a java command-line app.  I've configured the current session context to thread:

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

But when I invoke `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` it throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:348)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.get(Unknown Source)
....
```

I can use `openSession` and it won't really matter (it is a test after all).  I'm just curious why I can't get the method `getCurrentSession` to work as advertised.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first call to sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() does return a new session.  The problem was with my configuration.

I had it like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

After changing it to this, it worked:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Comment: Are you sure this fixed the issue?

Comment: I don't think this is a solution to this issue.

Comment: I had the same problem on Hibernate 4.2.8 and this solved my case!

Comment: @hba I have tired with your ans and fix problem but i want to know how is this possible ?. just explain me if you able please......

Comment: Sorry for the late delay in response.  I worked on this problem ages ago, got it working and moved on...i can't remember enough to respond this issue anymore...sorry

Comment: This resolved the same issue for me. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old question but thought of answering it right.

By changing the property name `hibernate.current_session_context_class` to `current_session_context_class`, forced default `JTASessionContext`.

Below snippet is from hibernate `SessionFactoryImpl`. BTW, `Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS` is `"hibernate.current_session_context_class"`. `ThreadLocalSessionContext` causes this issue.

```
private CurrentSessionContext buildCurrentSessionContext() {
        String impl = (String) properties.get( Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS );
        // for backward-compatibility
        if ( impl == null ) {
            if ( canAccessTransactionManager() ) {
                impl = "jta";
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        if ( "jta".equals( impl ) ) {
//          if ( ! transactionFactory().compatibleWithJtaSynchronization() ) {
//              LOG.autoFlushWillNotWork();
//          }
            return new JTASessionContext( this );
        }
        else if ( "thread".equals( impl ) ) {
            return new ThreadLocalSessionContext( this );
        }
        else if ( "managed".equals( impl ) ) {
            return new ManagedSessionContext( this );
        }
        else {
            try {
                Class implClass = serviceRegistry.getService( ClassLoaderService.class ).classForName( impl );
                return (CurrentSessionContext)
                        implClass.getConstructor( new Class[] { SessionFactoryImplementor.class } )
                        .newInstance( this );
            }
            catch( Throwable t ) {
                LOG.unableToConstructCurrentSessionContext( impl, t );
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please check `ThreadLocalSessionContext.TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke`